# How to implement fade in/out changing lines of text?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to do precisely what is illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/VB4QC/ but because I am out of my comfort zone, the bits that are not spelt out are stopping me from implementing it myself. Specifically I need to know what the Jquery include looks like, how to insert the Javascript, and how to call it. Let me show you what I'm currently guessing.

In the head of my document I add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

I have a local copy of this file and it works - tested with other elements, so the above seems fine.

To the Javascript given on the JSFiddle site I have added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
.
.
.
</script>
```

So to be literal, the body of my page contains:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var terms = ["term 1", "term 2", "term 3"];

function rotateTerm() {
  var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
  $("#rotate").data("term", ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(terms[ct]).fadeIn()
              .delay(2000).fadeOut(200, rotateTerm);
}
$(rotateTerm);
</script>
```

And lastly my guess was to call it with a body onload:

```
<body onload="rotateTerm()">
```

And of course the HTML body contains:

```
  <p>Here is a sentence <span id="rotate">this</span> is what changes</p>
```

So I am following the example as closely as I can (I think). What happens is that the page renders 
**Here is a sentence and: term 2 is what changes**
There is no fading up or down, and it doesn't display 'this', 'term 1' or 'term 3', although it looks as if 'term 1' flicks past in a millisecond.

What am I doing wrong? A little hand holding here would go a long way!

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: Where is your function `rotateTerm()` defined?

Comment: the javascript that you included here seems to be for something else. Try putting your code in jsfiddle and share it.

Comment: Thank you both - sorry for the confusion. I have been too long without sleep and I pasted in an unrelated piece of code which I have now corrected. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: can you make a fiddle demonstrating the issue with your code..? maybe while doing so itself you'll find the issue.. :)

Comment: Hi. I just set up a Jfiddle account to try to do as you ask. I find that Jfiddle is trying to force me to take the Javascript out of my HTML and put it in another panel. The integration of the two is I feel sue a key factor in what's going wrong here, so Jfiddle is disrupting the key to the problem. After all, I see a perfect working version of what I want to do in the Jfiddle I refered to above and I can't get it to work. decomposing it back would at best produce something identical to the Jfiddle I gave in the opening line. So I placed a copy here http://advancedvirtual.com/test/test.htm

Comment: Isn't that what the example is using? Is that what I'm doing wrong? What should I be using to make the example (http://jsfiddle.net/VB4QC/) work as it does?

Comment: I don't know how simply I can put this. Is there a single piece of HTML - one document - that contains the Javascript etc all in one place that that shows how to fade and changes text as per the http://jsfiddle.net/VB4QC/ example?

Comment: You can just choose on the left panel to put your JS in the head or body, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really sure if I understood your question correctly, but if a single document is what you want, there you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Here is a sentence <span id="rotate">this</span> is what changes</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var terms = ["term 1", "term 2", "term 3"];

      function rotateTerm() {
        var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
        $("#rotate").data("term", ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(terms[ct]).fadeIn()
                    .delay(2000).fadeOut(200, rotateTerm);
      }
      // Not needed anymore as the DOM is ready at this point
      // $(rotateTerm);
      // just call the function directly
      rotateTerm();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Personally I would do that script completely different, especially the data storage is unecessary imho.
Do you need an explanation of the code?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this, but it doesn't work. I tested it in the current version of Firefox and the word "this" does not change.

Comment: @FrankAnderson Works perfectly on FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera/… Replace the schema-relative jQuery inclusion with http/https if you open the file loaclly or open it via a local web server.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote up a walkthrough that explains what your fiddle is doing: http://rodney.is/rotating/text/. Since SO frowns on link-only answers, here's a quick-n-dirty solution.

Include jQuery like this, right before the closing  tag. Notice that you're using jQuery 1.3.1 and I'm including jQuery 1.11.0. I recommend you use the most recent version of jQuery that you can, because it will have fewer bugs and more features:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Include your script right after you include jQuery:

```
    <script>

var terms = ["term 1", "term 2", "term 3"];

function rotateTerm() {
    var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
    $("#rotate").data("term", ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(terms[ct]).fadeIn()
          .delay(2000).fadeOut(200, rotateTerm);
}
$(rotateTerm);

    </script>
```

You don't need `<body onload>` - the script will run as soon as it can, thanks to jQuery.

Comment: Hi Rodney. Thank you for your thoughtful input here. As a courtesy I wanted to say that I had just got the first responder's solution working. I was writing to thank him/her when your feedback came through. To be fair I should & will give the bounty to the first reply, but I want to acknowledge and thank both you for yours and pete for his too. Cheers!

Comment: And a footnote. Your blog walk-through was extremely thoughtful, helpful and well written. I really do appreciate the quality of your support which was excellent. Thank you indeed!

Answer (score 3):

Both [Rodney Folz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089026/rodney-folz) and [nietonfir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838733/nietonfir)'s answers are correct as both answers are using a higher version of jQuery than you are in your question (see http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
            jQuery 1.4 is the MINIMUM version required to make this work.
            This is because the .delay() method (used in rotateTerm() below)
            was not added to jQuery until v1.4:
                http://api.jquery.com/delay/

            jQuery can be linked in the head element, or the body (genuinely doesn't matter)
            provided it is linked prior to defining the other script (which uses jQuery).
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Here is a sentence <span id="rotate">this</span> is what changes</p>
        <!-- jQuery could also be linked here -->
        <script>
            var terms = ["term 1", "term 2", "term 3"];
            function rotateTerm() {
                var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0; // get current term, defaulting to 0 if there is no current term
                $("#rotate")    // find element with id="rotate" (span)
                    .data("term", ct == terms.length - 1 ? 0 : ct + 1) //store next term, looping to the beginning of the array as necessary
                    .text(terms[ct]) // set the text of the span
                    .fadeIn() // fade the element in from full transparency
                    .delay(2000) // wait 2 seconds <-- this is the reason you must use jQuery 1.4 or higher
                    .fadeOut(200, rotateTerm); // fade the element out to full transparency and call this function again
            }
            $(rotateTerm); // odd syntactical construct explained below
            /*
             * Most often, jQuery is used after the DOM content has been loaded and parsed into a DOM tree.
             * jQuery has a special contruct that greatly simplifies the syntax to catch the event.
             * The two most popular forms are below:

             $(document).ready(function () {
                // do stuff when DOM content is loaded and parsed.
             });

             * or 

             $(function () {
                // do stuff when DOM content is loaded and parsed.
             });

             * I have a strong tendency to use the former as I think it increases readability.
             * What the above odd syntactical construct is doing is using the latter form, but it is
             * substituting a named function (rotateTerm) for the anonymous function.
             */
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent point, and good eye. I didn't even realize the OP was using 1.3.1.

Comment: @RodneyFolz True. But who really would use such an old and obsolete version anyways?

Comment: @nietonfir - thank you!! You have solved my problem. And yes it needed the addition of 'http' in my case. By the way, in your first post you said you'd do the code differently - I'd be interested to see what and why if you are inclined to share that, but in any case, thank you for getting this working! pete - thank you for spotting the out of date Jquery reference. nietonfir - I would use an obsolete version - because as I said, I am out of my comfort zone with this stuff, a 'noobie' if you will & I am learning slowly. A sincere thank you to everyone for your help; you are much appreciated!

Comment: @FrankAnderson Your welcome. Well, one could use [CSS animations](http://jsbin.com/zoqeg/1), reduce the lookups by using [cache variables](http://jsbin.com/zoqeg/2) or using [`setTimeout()`](http://jsbin.com/zoqeg/3) instead of `$.delay()`, … but in all of these version I'd use a counter to set the text and not store it (and an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)).

Answer (score 1):

I have done it with CSS Animation. You can try this as alternative.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #rotate{animation: fadeIn 2s infinite;}
        @keyframes fadeIn{
            from {opacity: 0;}
            to {opacity: 1;}
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Here is a sentence <span id="rotate">this</span> is what changes</p>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var terms = ["term 1", "term 2", "term 3"];
        var count = 0;
        function setText(){
            $("#rotate").text(terms[count]);
            count++;
            if(count>=terms.length){
                count=0;
            }
        }
        var callFunction = setInterval(setText,2000);
        setText();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's nice Dharam, however the text changes during the fade, which isn't easy on the eye. Also, it fades in, but 'snaps' out, rather than fading out too. I imagine the first problem is to do with synchronisation errors of some sort, but I'm guessing as this area isn't my strong suit.

Comment: Yeap, I agree. I have just created it with use of CSS. I can do it with jQuery also, which can be fulfill your requirement. Do you want me  to provide you that also ?

Comment: I will never say no to an opportunity to learn something Dharam! However, only if you enjoy the teaching process, otherwise you might have other things that take priority to do. Whatever you decide, thank you!

Comment: See post below, added jQuery Version also.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery version, with the same effect which Frank Anderson was looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Here is a sentence <span id="rotate">this</span> is what changes</p>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var terms = ["term 1", "term 2", "term 3"];
        var count = 0;
        function setText(){
            $("#rotate").text(terms[count]).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
                $(this).animate({opacity:1},1000);
                setText();
            });
            count++;
            if(count>=terms.length){
                count=0;
            }
        }
     setText();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```